# tcolorbox: Rotated text at the frame border

Tags: tcolorbox, rotating

I am trying to put text at the left border of a box. Right now I have this:

```
\newtcolorbox{reminderbox}[1]{enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
colback=white,
colframe=black,
sharp corners,
underlay={%
    \path[draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle node[black,rotate=90]{\small #1} ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west);
}}
```

And I use it like this:

```
\begin{reminderbox}{For reference:}
    This is a well known fact!
\end{reminderbox}
```

which gives:
[image: The output with my problem]

How do I make the box to scale to the text?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it needs some extra work, but you can start with something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\mywidth}

\newtcolorbox{reminderbox}[1]{enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
colback=white,
colframe=black,
sharp corners,
underlay={%
    \path[draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle node[black,rotate=90]{\small #1} ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west);
},
code={\settowidth{\mywidth}{#1}},
height=\mywidth,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{reminderbox}{For reference:}
    This is a well known fact!
\end{reminderbox}

\begin{reminderbox}{Another reference:}
    This is a well known fact!
\end{reminderbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The remaining problem is that the box will not scale to large content. You can solve this with height plus=20cm (this is the maximum amount which can be added to the height, so choose something absurdly large, just to make sure it is enough in all cases)